# Swift Required initializers in EVReflection

Tags: swift, initializer

I'm writing code in Swift, and using https://github.com/evermeer/EVReflection.  However, Xcode is playing shenanigans with my class structure - in a few places, it claims I need to include a required initialized, declared in `EVObject`, but not in other places.  Consider the following example:

```
class Root: EVObject {
}

class MidA: Root {
    required init() {
    }

    init(blah: String) {
    }
}

class LeafA: MidA {
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
} // Error: 'required' initializer 'init(coder:)' must be provided by subclass of 'EVObject'

class MidB: Root {
    required init() {
    }
}

class LeafB: MidB {
    required init() {
        super.init()
    }
} // No error
```

`EVObject` contains the following method definition:

```
public convenience required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    self.init()
    EVReflection.decodeObjectWithCoder(self, aDecoder: coder, conversionOptions: .DefaultNSCoding)
}
```

Describing the example in words, there's a root object, `Root`, which extends `EVObject`, and it forks into two subclasses, `MidA` and `MidB`, which each have a subclass of their own: `LeafA` and `LeafB`.  `LeafA` and `LeafB` are identical aside from their name and superclass.  `MidA` and `MidB` differ only in name and in that `MidA` has an additional initializer that takes a parameter.

What bearing could that possibly have on `LeafA`?  Having an extra initializer with a parameter seems entirely unrelated to the particular initializer declared in `EVObject` (which is apparently `required`, but it's not usually enforced??).  Why would adding an unrelated initialized in a branch class suddenly require me, in my leaf classes, to figure out what the heck is this `required` initializer I've never seen before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's indeed caused by the extra init

```
init(blah: String) {
}
```

That one could also be changed to:

```
convenience init(blah: String) {
    self.init()
}
```

Then it won't complain about adding the required initializer.

With the convenience you specify that you will call a required initializer from there. Without that the compiler can't be sure that you do.

See also https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html